# How to validate password rules in java at server side,if password is encrypted using MD5?

Tags: java, validation, java-ee-6

```
    <!-- language: lang-java -->

        try 
        {
          DAO ddao = new DAO();
          HttpSession session = request.getSession();
          userBean ub = null;

          if (session.getAttribute("userdet") != null) 
          {
            ub = (userBean) session.getAttribute("userdet");
          }

          if (ub == null)   
          {
            return mapping.findForward("sesexpire");
          }

          if (!formValidation.validationTest(request)) 
          {
            session.invalidate();
            return mapping.findForward("hack");
          }

          if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getMethod()) && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) 
          {
            // how to perform server side validation for password field rules like
 1) Password must contain atleast eight characters.
    2) Password must not exceed 255 characters.
    3) Password must contain atleast one number (0-9)
    4) Password must contain atleast one lowercase letter (a-z)
    5) Password must contain atleast one uppercase letter (A-Z)
    6) Password must contain atleast one special character. due to md5 is applied at client side
          }
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
```

Comment: If you're using a secure connection on the client side, as you should be, then the MD5 encryption is redundant.

Comment: Well you could store the MD5 value in your database and do a string comparison but that's just equivalent to storing passwords in plain text. Maybe bcrypt the MD5 value?

Comment: Also, please note that MD5 is not an `encryption` algorithm but a `hash` algorithm.

Comment: @Trinopoty the query is about how to perform validations it is not about hashing techniques.

Comment: Ah I see. You're talking about password policy. I'm afraid there's no way to do that on the server side if you use MD5. You have to do it on the client side in this case.

Comment: You can't do this at all. And MD5 is secure(-ish) hashing, not encryption. You can't expect to misuse standard terminology without adverse comment.

Comment: @Trinopoty How about attacking things go on at server & DB when client-side validations are turned off.

Comment: That's the trade off. Either drop the MD5 or move the validation to the client.

Comment: How about both MD5 and validation is implemented at client-side and validation is dropped and MD5 is validated at server side ?

Comment: MD5 does not have a validation mechanism. The only thing you can check is if it's a hex string with a fixed length.

Comment: Please clarify what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Trinopoty said, MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, but a hashing one. This means that is one-way only, and you should not be able to reverse it.

However, this is no longer true for MD5 algorithm (and since many years from now).

One way you could do it is cracking the password. There are many implementations in github (just search for "MD5 rainbow tables"). Then, just perform the validations.

You can test it on online services like http://reversemd5.com/

Also, please note that this is heavily insecure (and performance costly). If you have a breach, having the passwords hashed in MD5 is the same that having them in plain text.

You should be using secure connection channels (HTTPS), receive the password in clear text, perform the validations and store it using a secure hashing mechanism (BCrypt or PBKDF2) when signing up or changing the password.

When an user logs in, just make the hash of the received password and compare it to the one you stored in the database.

Comment: Well yeah but cracking passwords is not feasible in real time and I think that's what OP is after.

Comment: you mean to say at server side validations are not achievable if hashing technique is done at client-side, which is mandatory even if the connection channel is secure has to be.

Comment: Any of the Latest and more secure hashing mechanism is allowed for reversible? If yes validations at server side can be possible.

Comment: @Trinopoty not necessarily. If you precompute the rainbow tables, you will get the result almost instantly. However, the size of those tables are usually high, or length constrained. You can find a list of available tables here: project-rainbowcrack.com/table.htm.
Ajay, no hashing mechanism can be reversed. Hash is a one-way function. But you should think about requirements. Using MD5 is the same as using nothing. It was cracked years ago and provides no enhance of security. If you want two-way, why not use base64 instead? Just make sure that you store it properly hashed in the DB

Comment: You wouldn't want MD5 cracking in a production environment as far as I understand. Also, rainbow tables almost never give you the exact input you actually entered. Tons and tons of input values compute to the same MD5 hash.

Comment: You are completely right, you don't want an MD5 cracking in a production environment. You also do not want to reverse the hash in any situation that is not cracking, but that was the question about. It's the only option he has. He either uses the cracking, and deals with collision in any way, or changes the requirements (which is, in my opinion, what he should do)